# Using batch to run multiple java programs

Tags: java, batch-file

I wrote a batch file to run multiple batch files which run a java program separately. I am wondering if I need to pass an argument to the java program when I run it, how do I pass the argument when I start the station batch files?
The main batch file looks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
set CLASSPATH=.
ECHO open Server 

start Server.bat
ECHO open station1

start station1.bat
ECHO open station2 

start station2.bat
ECHO open station3 

start station3.bat
ECHO open station4 
start station4.bat
```

The station batch file looks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
set CLASSPATH=.
java ClientStation  arg1  arg2   arg3
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change station.bat from

```
java ClientStation  arg1  arg2   arg3
```

to

```
java ClientStation  %*
```

which will pass command line arguments on to `ClientStation`. And when you call it, call it like

```
start station1.bat arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Or use `%*` if you want to pass command line arguments from that script onto `station.bat`

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work. station1.bat just doesn't run.

Comment: My bad, I got something wrong. It actually works. Thank you so much!